# Sharing data between processes in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, lazy-evaluation, sharing

I have a complex data structure (user-defined type) on which a large number of independent calculations are performed. The data structure is basically immutable. I say basically, because though the interface looks immutable, internally some lazy-evaluation is going on. Some of the lazily calculated attributes are stored in dictionaries (return values of costly functions by input parameter).
I would like to use Pythons [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) module to parallelize these calculations. There are two questions on my mind.

1. How do I best share the data-structure between processes?
2. Is there a way to handle the lazy-evaluation problem without using locks (multiple processes write the same value)?

Thanks in advance for any answers, comments or enlightening questions!

Comment: How large / complex are you talking? When an `independent calculation` is submitted, do you know before the start which lazy attributes are needed?

Comment: The problem is basically a leave-one-out cross-validation on a large set of data-samples. It takes about two hours on my machine on a single core, but I have access to a machine with 24 cores and would like to leverage that power. I do not know in advance which of the attributes will be needed by a single calculation, but I know that eventually (over all calculations) all attributes will be needed, so I could just load them all up front (would have to test that though).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How do I best share the data-structure between processes?

Pipelines.

```
origin.py | process1.py | process2.py | process3.py
```

Break your program up so that each calculation is a separate process of the following form.

```
def transform1( piece ):
    Some transformation or calculation.
```

For testing, you can use it like this.

```
def t1( iterable ):
    for piece in iterable:
        more_data = transform1( piece )
        yield NewNamedTuple( piece, more_data )
```

For reproducing the whole calculation in a single process, you can do this.

```
for x in t1( t2( t3( the_whole_structure ) ) ):
    print( x )
```

You can wrap each transformation with a little bit of file I/O.  Pickle works well for this, but other representations (like JSON or YAML) work well, too.

```
while True:
    a_piece = pickle.load(sys.stdin)
    more_data = transform1( a_piece )
    pickle.dump( NewNamedTuple( piece, more_data ) )
```

Each processing step becomes an independent OS-level process.  They will run concurrently and will -- immediately -- consume all OS-level resources.

> Is there a way to handle the lazy-evaluation problem without using locks (multiple processes write the same value)?

Pipelines.

Comment: Wow, that answers solves two problems that where not even in my question (how to send a complex object to another process, how to do this in python when the multiprocessing-module is not available)!

Comment: The point is that OS-level (shared buffer) process management is (a) simpler and (b) can be as fast as more complex multi-threaded, shared-everything techniques.

Comment: @S.Lott I want to share numpy random state of a parent process with a child process. I've tried using `Manager` but still no luck. Could you please take a look at my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49372619/how-to-share-numpy-random-state-of-a-parent-process-with-child-processes) and see if you can offer a solution? I can still get different random numbers if I do `np.random.seed(None)` every time that I generate a random number, but this does not allow me to use the random state of the parent process, which is not what I want. Any help is greatly appreciated.